# How to design models.py in django to Insert QueryDict

Tags: python, django

My forms.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from item.models import *
from django import forms


class catalogForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label=_("Catalog Title"))
    #item = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.exclude(user=1), widget=forms.SelectMultiple)

    #def __init__(self, userId, *args, **kwargs):
        #super(catalogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.fields['item'].queryset = Item.objects.filter(user = userId)
    def __init__(self, qs=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(catalogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if qs:
            self.fields['item'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=qs, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from item.models import Item
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Catalog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My views.py

```
def catalog(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    qs = Item.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = catalogForm(qs,request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            title=form.cleaned_data['title']
            item=form.cleaned_data['item']
            user= request.user
            q = Catalog(title=title, pub_date=timezone.now(),user=user)
            q.save()
            q.item = item.values()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = catalogForm(qs)

    return render(request, 'catalog/catalog.html', {'form': form})
```

So I want to select multiple `Items` from `Combo box` and insert their `ID` against a particular `catalog`. Also want to retrieve later each `Items Id` for a particular `catalog`. What is the best way to design `models.py` for this in `django`

Right now if I try to insert with this code I am able to insert into `catalog_catalog` only , how to insert into selected `item` into `catalog_catalog_item` table

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need this model field instead (remember to run migrations):

```
item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

then upon saving form, you firstly save the catalog object and then you add related items:

```
items = form.cleaned_data['items']

q = Catalog(title=title, pub_date=timezone.now(), user=user)
q.save()
q.items = items.values()
```

Use `items.values()` to get ids from items querydict.

Comment: Also `item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)` It will create 2 tables `catalog_catalog` and `catalog_catalog_item`. Will `q = Catalog(title=title, pub_date=timezone.now(), user=user)
q.save()` this save data in both the tables ?